# edX MongoDB connection error 111

Tags: mongodb, edx

When I try to login to the edX Studio I always get a connection error:

```
ConnectionFailure at /home/
[Errno 111] Connection refused

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8001/home/
Django Version: 1.4.20
Exception Type: ConnectionFailure
Exception Value: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Exception Location: /edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py in __init__, line 369
Python Executable: /edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

I've done my due diligence on Google and did the:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

sudo mongod --repair

sudo service mongodb start
```

and all it's variations and nothing did the trick.

Can somebody help me, please?
Thanks for reading.

EDIT: The error occurs when I try to login to the edX Studio via:
staff@example.com
edx

I get a login success message on the server but immediately after that I get that error.

Comment: Check ports and firewall settings. Is the service indeed running on port 8001, is 8001 open?

Comment: Actually I can open localhost:8001. I get that error when trying to login to the edX Studio with username: staff@example.com pass: edx

Comment: Did you check this page: https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Developer-Stack ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
sudo rm /edx/var/mongo/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo -u mongodb mongod --dbpath /edx/var/mongo/mongodb --repair --repairpath /edx/var/mongo/mongodb
sudo start mongodb
```

I've got this from [this](http://ianhowson.com/open-edx-setting-up-devstack.html) site, many thanks to the author.
In my case the last line was:

```
sudo start mongod
```

without the 'b' at the end.

Thanks everyone for your efforts!

UPDATE:

If you get this error `sudo: /etc/init.d/mongod: command not found` when running the script on Ubuntu 16.04. host, try this command:

```
sudo rm /edx/var/mongo/mongodb/mongod.lock && sudo mongod -repair --config /etc/mongod.conf && sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /edx/var/mongo/. && sudo systemctl start mongod.service
```

It's the same as the last one, except it's a one-liner and the last part is replaced with the *systemctl start* command.

Comment: Thanks for sharing solution. Most people don't share even after they solve problems on their own.

Comment: @sherlock92, been there that's why I do it. No problem! :)

Comment: I literally just had this problem today. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thanks Vedran. The last command worked fine in my case using the release ficus.3

Comment: Thanks for  your answer save my time.

Answer (score 6):

This set of commands solved my problem (similar to Vedran's solution):

```
sudo rm /edx/var/mongo/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo mongod -repair --config /etc/mongod.conf
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /edx/var/mongo/.
sudo service mongod start
```

This happens always when you shutdown your pc with the vagrant machine running. So my recommendation is to perform a 'vagrant halt' before shutting down your host machine.

Comment: precisely I turned off my laptopt without used vagrant halt.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this commands in vagrant

```
sudo rm /edx/var/mongo/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongod start
```